# How could I classify every county in this US as flat, hilly, or moderate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, elevation, spatial-statistics, mapping, topography

I'm looking for a VERY rough label for every county, so low-res data is fine here. Is there data on existing elevation change per county? Or should I get an elevation layer of the US and do a zonal summary of intersecting features? Where could I find a rough elevation raster of the US?

Comment: There are a bunch of question here. I don't understand what you mean. Please clarify your question? What are you exactly looking for?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.  GIS SE is not a discussion site. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, which doesn't work well with brainstorming questions. In theory, this would be appropriate in [Chat], but our Chat is *underutilized*, and it has a minimum reputation requirement that boxes out new users.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.[Is it wise to summarize the flatness of a county with the statistic Elevation variance per square mile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372411/is-it-wise-to-summarize-the-flatness-of-a-county-with-the-statistic-elevation-va)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are datasets specifically of elevation change, but conceptually it wouldn't be hard to create this yourself. You could run [Zonal Statistics as Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) on a DEM, using county boundaries for your zone dataset. If you output all the statistics not only would you get range, but you could also get min, max, and std (plus many others) which could provide more perspective on how much the elevation changes than just range. The biggest challenge with this is the size of the data you are working with - a DEM covering the entire US is going to be big data whether it is a 30m DEM or a 1km DEM. Consider what resolution you want to process the DEM at, and how you are going to do the processing so that the file sizes won't crash your machine.

I would also you to consider how are you planning on using the elevation change data, as that might influence DEM resolution, which statistics to output, and whether or not you really need to process the entire country (i.e. if you are doing some kind of suitability modeling could you use other variables to select a subset of counties?).