# Summarizing flatness of county with statistic Elevation variance per square mile

Tags: r, topography

I need to classify every county in the US as either hilly, moderately hilly, or flat. Accuracy is not critical, just a rough classification. I used R and followed the advice in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293993/plotting-and-analyzing-extracted-elevation-data-in-r/294282#294282) answer to import elevation and counties and calculated the zonal variance. This was inherently biased towards larger counties since they have more surface for hills, so I need to divide by area.

If I divide variance by square miles does that reasonably represent hilliness?

The preliminary results seem decent, with the highest values being places like Colorado, Hawaii, Montana, etc.

Comment: This is a profoundly bad idea as it will be very misleading in representing processes such as "hilliness" or dissection. You could have a very high variance with a small feature, occupying an extremely small proportion of the state that is otherwise flat, that is equal to a state that has consistent relief.

Comment: You could try standard deviation of a slope derived from the DEM (in UTM projection) instead of min/max, the size of the first standard deviation would eliminate outliers like a pinnacle or open cut mine then but counties that are larger with on a natural slope would have essentially the same slope then the standard deviation of the slope is small. What cell size are you working with? A large cell size would be more representative but a small cell size has potential for localized changes that could introduce false positives.

Comment: So if I take the square root I get the standard deviation which is the same units as the data? Since the purpose is to estimate cell tower coverage I would want to keep the effects of mines and pinnacles. The elevation data comes from ahttps://registry.opendata.aws/terrain-tiles/ or 
 https://github.com/tilezen/joerd/blob/master/docs/data-sources.md. It says 10m resolution, 430m ground resolution. 

How would I get a DEM file that has slope for the US? The USGS only has a bunch of small tiles

Comment: Your hypothesis directly implies that the data would be highly skewed. As such, your +/- SD would, in many cases, fal, outside your observed distribution. You could derive a metric that represents topographic completely or divergence, sum it for the aggregate and then normalize by area.

Comment: variance already takes the number of pixels into account, so I would not divide by the area a second time.

Comment: I found a new metric - Roughness : (https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/roughness.html)

Will taking the mean of this value for every county be a good summary of hilliness? The hilliest counties I got were all in Colorado, Washington, Idaho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the concept of [rugosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugosity), specifically the [Arc-chord ratio](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10980-014-0118-8#page-1) (Du Preez, 2015). Basically, you take the area of a triangulation of the surface and the plane-of-best-fit to the edges of the surface.

Note that the fractal dimension is important: as the surface resolution increases, the surface area of its triangulation approaches infinity, so your entire dataset needs to have the same resolution. You don't mention which dataset you're using but SRTM would be ideal. The solution is robust to instances, like that mentioned by a commenter, where there's a single, tall structure on a mostly-flat terrain.

The algorithm should be fairly simple to implement in R (though I'm not able to post example code -- I've implemented it in C++ using the same general approach):

1. Convert the cells in the county to points, with the elevation as Z.
2. Perform a 3D Delaunay triangulation on the points.
3. Sum the area of the facets of the triangulation (one side only, obvs.)
4. Extract the points from the exterior ring of the triangulation and compute the plane-of-best-fit for those points, with the same bounding polygon as the triangulation.
5. Take the ratio of the areas of the triangulated surface and the POBF. This is the ACR.

One issue I foresee is the the memory requirement for geometric operations on the county level. You might have to down-sample the elevation raster or break up the work into smaller chunks and aggregate the result. You could run the entire country at some sampling resolution and then perform zonal statistics on the result by county.

(Note: I'm not certain that this is a good strategy and look forward to hearing from other members why that might or might not be so.)

Comment: I found a new metric - Roughness : (https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/roughness.html)

Comment: Will taking the mean of this value for every county be a good summary of hilliness? The hilliest counties I got were all in Colorado, Washington, Idaho.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, except that if your definition of "hilliness" equals the definition of "roughness" then possibly. You have to decide what that is. I would consult any literature you can find on the matter and see which methods practitioners in the field use. Disciplines develop cultural affinities for certain methods and it's better not to reinvent the wheel.

GDAL's algorithm is much simpler and faster than ACR (which is used to study the roughness of corals) and gives a result per pixel, rather than per cluster. You can definitely use zonal stats to aggregate those.